# Delphi : variable array of thread not execute all index of array

Tags: delphi, pascal

I made a thread to execute records to the table, and I did the call using looping as in the following code. which is the problem of 100 loops, not all variable I values are inputted into the table.

```
{ TDBThread }

    procedure TDBThread.Execute;
    begin
      InsertDB(Fid);
    end;

    procedure TDBThread.InsertDB(Aid: Integer);
    var
      oConn: TFDConnection;
      oQry: TFDQuery;
    begin
      oConn := TFDConnection.Create(nil);
      oConn.ConnectionDefName := 'smen';
      oQry := TFDQuery.Create(nil);
      oQry.Connection := oConn;
      try
        try
          oQry.SQL.Text := 'insert into thethread (id,msg) values (:id,''Thread'')';
          oQry.ParamByName('id').AsInteger := Aid;
          oQry.ExecSQL;
        except
        end;
      finally
        oConn.Close;
        oQry.Connection := nil;
        oQry.Free;
        oConn.Free;
      end;
    end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    var
      I: Integer;
      dbThread: array of TDBThread;
    begin
      SetLength(dbThread,100);
      for I := 0 to 99 do
      begin
        Application.ProcessMessages;
        dbThread[I] := TDBThread.Create(True);
        dbThread[I].FreeOnTerminate := True;
        dbThread[I].id := I+1;
        dbThread[I].Start;
        Sleep(1);
      end;
    end;
```

Comment: Have you tried logging whatever comes up in the except ? Maybe there are some key violations when inserting or something, but you cannot see them since your except clause is empty

Comment: OK So you can rule that out. But can you please edit the question and add the new code there, not in a comment.

Comment: Surely this code, even if you can make it work correctly, will be very much slower than a single SQL command

Comment: Log all calls to `InsertDB` (First line in that method).

Comment: Where is FID implementation and how your code generate it ?

Comment: @MojtabaTajik I'm guessing that FID is a private field of TDBThread. Its value seems to be set using ID property of TDBThread after it is created in Button1Click method.

Comment: Certainly looks like `InsertDB(Fid);` might be better as `InsertDB(self.id);` but we need to the definition of `TDBThread` to tell.

Comment: Maybe concurrency problem? Have you tried use critical section just to check?

Comment: thanks GuidoG sorry for breaking the rule.
David Heffernan, you're right this code use very large resources.

i found the problem in FDManager definition, I do not define the maximum pool on FDManager.